# How to use QueryTable.BeforeRefresh event?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Microsoft documents a [QueryTable.BeforeRefresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.beforerefresh) event for Excel. I'd love to use it to clear the values from some columns added to the table where a query loads. Here's a pic of the situation:
[image: table excerpt]

My problem is, I don't know where to put or how to name a VBA subroutine that I want to run every time my query refreshes, whether it refreshes automatically or because the user requests it to.

So, if my query is called prepareForMS, how do I hook into its `BeforeRefresh` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the event like this - code is in the worksheets module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents qt As QueryTable

Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
MsgBox "after refresh"
End Sub

Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox "Before refresh"
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Set qt = Me.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
End Sub
```

`qt` gets initialized whenever you activate the according sheet.

Comment: When you say "worksheets module" do you mean I need to put this on each worksheet? Or do you mean it goes on the Workbook?

Comment: It is possible to have classes for generic routines - but basically you have to instantiate the QueryTable on each sheet

Comment: It appears that `WithEvents` is only valid inside a class module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler

Comment: That's true - a worksheet module or a class module. That's why I wrote that you either have to place it in each worksheet module or create a class and create an instance per each worksheet.